# zend framework 2 routing going to incorrect action

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I am trying to hit the **datatable** action with the sID and cID params.

**/CustomerManager/datatable/123/100**

When the above url is hit it goes to the refreshdata see below image.
[image]

Working fine when the url is

**/CustomerManager/datatable**

Can anyone see problem with the config?

```
'CustomerManager' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/CustomerManager[/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'CustomerManager\Controller\CustomerManager',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'datatable' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:sID][/:cID]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'cono' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                            'cust' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'datatable',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'refreshdata' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:showDel][/:sID][/:cID]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'refreshdata'
                        ),
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'showDel' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                            'sID' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                            'cID' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
```

Comment: Your routing doesn't make sense and your constraint names don't match route segments (`cono` and `cust` are nowhere in your route). I would suggest that you read [the documentation on Routing](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) more carefully. Try to split the router config into smaller segments that will make it more understandable. For example `CustomerManager`, `datatable` and `refreshtable` could be literal routes.

Answer (score 2):

it seems "refreshdata" overwrite "datatable" because you expect a url with at last 3 parameter which all can be letters or numbers

and in request you call a url with two number type parameters which matches with "refreshdata"

also I think

```
'cono' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
'cust' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
```

in this line "cono" and "cust" must change to "sID" and "cID"

Comment: also I think /datatable/[:sID][/:cID] or /datatable/[:sID[/:cID]] would work if you don't expect like /whateverElse/23/45 then you should keep your rule just make some changes to make them unique comparing to one another. zend will match from last one to the first one

Comment: This will not solve OP's problem as the optional routing of the segments fall within the constraints of other routes. So the answer of @Wilt is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

After my comment an example on how you declare your routes more structured:

```
'router' => array(
    'CustomerManager' => array(
        'CustomerManager' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/CustomerManager',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // Literal route for data table
                'datatable' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/datatable',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'datatable',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        // Child route for table cell
                        'cell' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/[:sID][/:cID]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'sID'=> '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                                    'cID' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                // Literal route for refreshtable
                'refreshtable' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/refreshtable',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'refreshtable',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        // Child route for table cell
                        'cell' => array(
                            'type' => 'segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/[:sID][/:cID]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'sID'=> '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                                    'cID' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

This is simply an example you can change it after your specific needs.

---

### EDIT

Understanding the basics of routing is important for building a proper application. You should read the [ZF2 Routing documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) thoroughly, all the information you need is in there...

For example:

In the question the `sID` and `cID` segments are optional (between square brackets). This will most likely also not work as you expect. A problem might occur when column `cID` is given but no `sID` value is given. The router will attach the `cID` value to the `sID` parameter name in such case, leading to unexpected route parameter values in your match.

Something like this could be solved by doing something like this with your constraints:

```
'constraints' => array(
    'sID' => 's[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
    'cID' => 'c[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+' 
),
```

By preceding the regular expression constraints (and the values in the url) with either an `s` or a `c` you make sure the correct value is tied to the correct parameter.

Comment: Just a small addition: using brackets (like: [:/id]) within your Segment routes make them optional. So OP should try to decide whether or not the parameters per route are optional or required.

Comment: @Kwido, true. In the question they were optional, so I assume OP wants these columns/rows optional. A problem might occur when column `cID` is given and no `sID` value is given. Route will attach the cID value to the `sID` parameter name in such case. Could be solved by doing: `'sID' => 's[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'` and `'cID' => 'c[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'`

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same as OP set everything as optional. You could update your answer with what you explained within the comment, to make your answer even better. As one should really consider how to set up their routes properly, even considering prefixes for routeParameters when needed if the use case is there.